# Extending laws for Riemann integral to Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: analysis, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

I was reading Terence Tao's notes on Analysis. He says Theorem 13(g) cannot be extended from Riemann integral to Riemann-Stieltjes integral:

> Most (but not all) of the remaining theory from Week 9 notes then can
>   be carried over without difficulty, replacing Riemann integrals with
>   Riemann-Stieltjes integrals and lengths with $\alpha$-length. (There
>   are a couple results which break down; **Theorem 13(g)**, Proposition
>   16, and Proposition 17 are not necessarily true when $\alpha$ is
>   discontinuous at key places (e.g. if $f$ and $\alpha$ are both
>   discontinuous at the same point, then $\int_{I}fd\alpha$ is unlikely
>   to be defined).
>
> Source: page 4 of [week 10 notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131ah.1.03w/week10.pdf)

But I do not see why Theorem 13(g) breaks down if we extend it to Riemann-Stieltjes integral. Can anyone explain? Below is the theorem:

> Theorem 13 (Laws of integration). Let $I$ be a generalized interval,
>   and let $f: I \rightarrow R$ and $g: I \rightarrow R$ be Riemann
>   integrable functions on I.
>
> ...
>
> (g) Let $J$ be a generalized interval containing $I$ (i.e. $I \subseteq J$), and let $F: J \rightarrow R$ be the function
>
> $$ F(x) := \left\{
>                  \begin{array}{ll}
>                    f(x) & \text{if } x \in I \\
>                    0    & \text{if } x \notin I
>                  \end{array}
>                \right. $$
>
> Then $F$ is Riemann integrable on $J$, and $\int_{J}F = \int_{I}f$.
>
> Source: page 14 of [week 9 notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131ah.1.03w/week9.pdf)